# I have a problem in user redirecting in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am a beginner and I am creating a forum using html, css, bootstrap, python and django. I created a view for deleting posts:

```
 class DeletePost(DeleteView):
     model = Post
     success_url = '/'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(author_post_id=self.request.user.id)
```

When a user will click the "Confirm button", when he need to remove a post, i would like to redirect him to the same discussion's page in which there was the post that he deleted, but i don't know how.
Can somebody help? Thanks in advance.

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_author = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    content = models.TextField(default="Your content here...")
    creation_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    discussion = ForeignKey(Discussion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_author.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

Urls:

Discussion's url:

```
path('discussion/<int:pk>', views.view_discussion, name='view_discussion')
```

DeleteView's url:

```
path('discussion/<int:id>/delete_post/<int:pk>/', views.DeletePost.as_view(), name='delete_post')
```

Comment: Can you specify the url of your discussion page where the post has been deleted. You probably should share relevant parts of the `Post` model as well.

Comment: Yes, here they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `get_success_url` with:

```
class DeletePost(DeleteView):
     model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            author_post_id=self.request.user.id
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('view_discussion', kwargs={'pk': self.object.discussion_id})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect. I only replaced 'id' with 'pk' for adjust it according to my url.

Comment: @Klebe: argh... yes, that was a mistake. Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'redirect' method in Django.

First import it: `from django.shortcuts import redirect`

then write this one line of code : `return redirect('/nameOfURL')` under your class/function based views.

Update :

```
def delete_post(request, id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    pi = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
    pi.delete()
    return redirect('/view_discussion')
```

Comment: Ok, but there are a lot of discussions, not only one. So, how can i redirect the user to the specific discussion in wich there was the deleted post?

Comment: I have updated and written a function-based view. See if this can help you. In the update, if a post will be deleted. It will be redirected to the view_discussion URL.